# TOR crashed and left other USB thumb drive encrypted

Tags: security

I was browsing with TOR and I had a second USB drive plugged into the computer, I have previously saved data to that drive in other sessions but I did not write anything to the second USB during the last session when it crashed.  I may have accessed the second drive but I’m unsure.  When I restarted Tails the second drive shows as encrypted and I can’t access it.

Why has the second drive been encrypted and how do I get the data back from that USB drive?  The drive is not normally encrypted, it’s just a drive I use to transfer data between machines.

Does Tails do some sort of encryption on any drive you access?  Do you lose all your data in an access device if Tails crashes?

Comment: Just a guess, but did you maybe run a ransomware program? Or are you using an old version of Tails?

Comment: By ‘did you run’ do you mean I deliberately downloaded one or is Tails subject to getting infected?  I didn’t download one and no screen telling me to give them my first born came up.  This has happened before but last time the USB was blank, just showed up as encrypted.  This time there is data I didn’t really want to lose, it wasn’t encrypted in any way, there’s nothing of great secrecy just photos I spent a lot of time editing for a club meet.